# Java (Tomcat) equivalent for HttpApplication in ASP.NET

Tags: session, tomcat, memcached, replication, cluster-computing

I'm looking for Java (Tomcat) equivalent for HttpApplication in ASP.NET. My business requires to store some temporary data globally at runtime. I would like to do it in HttpApplication if I'm using ASP.NET. What is the Java approach with Tomcat?

Furthermore, I'm using Tomcat cluster + memcached session manager with non-session sticky in backend. Both session and application data are expected to be replicated in realtime.

Any comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent is the ServletContext that you can access using getServletContext in your servlet. In JSP you can access it with the application variable.

You can store your data in the context attribute Map.

Tomcat cluster replicates sessions and servlet context attributes

Comment: Hi Stéphane, I did store my data in ServletContext as you pointed. But I found it doesn't get replicated by MSM (memcached session manager with non-session sticky). Only session data is replicated correctly. Any comments?

Comment: I am not familiar with memncahed session manager , however from what I can tell from a quick read of the page and from the title that it only put session in memcached. The cluster solution I was referring to was Tomcat built in cluster which if configured to do so can replicate attributes. see .ReplicatedContext on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/cluster.html

Comment: MSM doesn't support ServletContext replication, pointed by Martin Grotzke himself (The author of MSM). Then I will find another way to do it. Thanks.